# Confine code to a set dimension for print

Tags: html

I've grabbed this template for use on a website I'm trying to sort out, and I'm needing to allow it to print to a set dimension to work with my label printer. (62x90mm). Here is the code I have but I'm having difficulties making it match the 62x90mm dimensions as described above.

```
{% if shipping_address %}
<div style="padding: 1.5em; border: 1px solid black;">
<h2 style="margin: 0 0 1em 0;">Recipient</h2>
<strong>{{ shipping_address.name }}</strong><br/>
{% if shipping_address.company %}
{{ shipping_address.company }}<br/>
{% endif %}
{{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
{{ shipping_address.city }} {{ shipping_address.province_code }} {{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}<br/>
{{ shipping_address.country }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

Now changed it to this:

```
{% if shipping_address %}
<div style="padding: 1.5em; border: 1px solid black; height: 210px; width: 320px; font-size: 20px">
<h2 style="margin: 0 0 0.2em 0;">Send To</h2>
<strong>{{ shipping_address.name }}</strong><br/>
{% if shipping_address.company %}
{{ shipping_address.company }}<br/>
{% endif %}
{{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
{{ shipping_address.city }}
{{ shipping_address.province_code }}<br/>
{{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}<br/>
{{ shipping_address.country }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```

It gives a visual output like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuUgf.png

But it prints on two pieces of label (62X90mm) with the name and first line of the address on the one piece, followed by the City, Postcode and Country.

Answer (score 0):

Use mm for size, look here:
https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Fall back to percentage sizes for IE8 and below.

Looking at your code, I think your best bet is to wrap the whole in a div and using media queries and conditional comments. Let me know if you need more detail, it's late here.

Comment: I've tried changing up the code, but it's still printing wrongly. It's printing on two pieces of label. Knowing my luck It's probably incorrect as coding is not my best ability.

Comment: Label printers are an entirely separate species. I'm afraid I can't help you much further there.

Good luck!

Comment: Just a thought; but have you tried spoecifying these in mm as the link I gave you explains? 

    height: 210px; width: 320px;